# Find all the equilibrium solutions of $x' = \cos(x^2)$ and determine stability.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, dynamical-systems

One can determine equilibrium solutions of autonomous EDO's setting the derivative equal to zero. So, in this case, all the equilibrium solutions take the form $x^* = \pm \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi}$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, right?

Well, good, now I have to determine their stability. IMHO, we can separate the analysis in two cases: when $k$ is even and when it's odd. In the first loop, if we get, say, $k=0$ we have $x^* = \sqrt{\pi/2}$. If $x<x^*$, then $\cos(x^2)>0$. In the other hand, if $x>x^*$, $\cos(x^2)<0$. So, the "$k$-even" equilibria should be all stable.

If we proceed the same way for an odd $k$, say $k=1$, we get quite the opposite and the "$k$-odd" equilibria should be all unstable.

But I have two questions regarding my "solution". 1) Can i just ignore that some arcs are negative (I've just analyzed positive ones because they all go squared so it should make no difference in my opinion)? 2) The conditions about the derivatives that I used to characterize the stability are ok, right? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The derivative check is enough, given that $cos(x^2)$ is a nice, locally-lipschitz function. However, checking $-\sqrt{\pi/2}$ says that if you move to the left of it, you have negative derivative, and on its right you have positive derivative. So, things reverse.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. The behavior of k-even equilibria is different from the k-odd equilibria, all set. But the question is if I don't really nee to mind the the negative arcs. In my view, as $3\pi/4 = -\pi/2$ in terms of checking the validity of argument, everything is in place. Right?

Comment: The difference between $3\pi/4 $ and $ -\pi/2$ is that in one the function is decreasing, but increasing in the other. SO, they are not really the same from the point of view of the analysis of this system.

Comment: @Moo yeah, I realized that using the derivative test is the best way to deal with this kind of problem.